# Delete a value from the vector for the key

Tags: c++

I have a map like
`typedef map<int32_t,std::vector<int32_t>> myMap`

I have added a value in vector with respect to the key like

```
myMap[somePointer->getVal()].push_back(Id1);
myMap[somePointer->getVal()].push_back(Id2);
myMap[somePointer->getVal()].push_back(Id3);
myMap[somePointer->getVal()].push_back(Id4);
```

What if I want to delete a value from the vector for the key?
I tried doing 
`myMap[somePointer->getVal()].erase(Id1)`

But with this compiler cries with errors.

Comment: Do you know about multimap? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/

Comment: @billz: Agree in that the error is always helpful, and should be required. In this particular case for people that are familiar with the vector interface it is obvious that the issue is trying to `erase` a value, not an iterator... but yes: *please provide error messages when you ask about compiler errors!*

Answer (score 1):

Try this to delete the `x+1`th element

`myMap[somePointer->getVal()].erase (myMap[somePointer->getVal()].begin()+x);`

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/), the synopsys is:

C++98:

```
iterator erase (iterator position);
iterator erase (iterator first, iterator last);
```

C++11:

```
iterator erase (const_iterator position);
iterator erase (const_iterator first, const_iterator last);
```

So you have to give an iterator.

```
it = myMap[somePointer->getVal()].begin() + index;
myMap[somePointer->getVal()].erase(it)
```

You can also try to use [`multimap`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/) for this.

Answer (score 0):

Vectors are not designed for lookup, so the interface is not based on values. If you want to erase from a vector you need to know the location. The good thing is that you can get the location by using standard algorithms. The equivalent of your code would be:

```
auto& vector = myMap[somePointer->getVal()];
auto it = std::find(vector.begin(), vector.end(), Id1);
if (it != vector.end()) { vector.erase(it); }
```

As you can see it is a bit longer and more convoluted than your original. If you have the position of the element in the vector (i.e. if you know you want to erase the first/last/nth element) you can substitute the `std::find` for the correct iterator obtained by means of `begin()`, `end()` and iterator arithmetic.

Comment: I tried this doing the similar thing. The code gets compiled.
    std::vector<int32_t> temp = myMap[somePointer->getVal()];
    std::vector<int32_t>::iterator it = 
                  std::find(temp.begin(),temp.end(),Id);
    if (it != temp.end()) 
    {    
        temp.erase(it); 
    }    
But I am not sure whether this deletes Id from the vector or not.
I am very weak in vectors.
I tried this doing the similar thing. The code gets compiled.But I am not sure whether this would give me the correct output.

Comment: @user2815287: Print the contents of the vector and check it.

Answer (score 0):

For C++98 or C++11, the `erase` has three overloaded format

C+98

```
void erase (iterator position);
size_type erase (const key_type& k);
void erase (iterator first, iterator last);
```

C++11

```
iterator  erase (const_iterator position);
size_type erase (const key_type& k);
iterator  erase (const_iterator first, const_iterator last);
```

So you should use the second format as the following to delete

```
myMap.erase(somePointer->getVal()); // getVal() must return a type convertible to maps key_type
```

instead of

```
myMap[somePointer->getVal()].erase(Id1)
```